# Wildcard for file encoding in org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs?

Tags: eclipse

We have a file naming convention in our CVS project to end a file name with `.utf8.txt` for text files that use UTF-8 encoding.  The problem is I currently have to manually tell Eclipse the file encoding every time I create one of these files by right-clicking the file, selecting 'Properties', then changing the encoding in the drop-down.  Now I have a project where I need to add and remove these files often, and it's become quite a pain to have to do this by hand.  I'd like to be able to specify somewhere once and for all that files with a name ending in `.utf8.txt` shall use the UTF-8 encoding.

I've noticed when I make the preference change, Eclipse modifies the `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` Settings file to add the following line:

> `encoding/file.utf8.txt=UTF-8`

So naturally, the first thing I tried was using an asterisk wildcard.  However, neither of these worked:

> `encoding/*.utf8.txt=UTF-8`
>   `encoding/**.utf8.txt=UTF-8`

Is what I want even possible in Eclipse?  Also, is the file format for `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` documented somewhere?

Comment: What's your eclipse default setting for the encoding in the preferences?
Under General->Workspace set it to Other and type UTF-8

Comment: This may be an option, but I'd have to get the rest of the dev team to sign off on it as well.  I was hoping for a quick fix.

Comment: I found a solution to my immediate problem.  I am able to group all of the .utf8.txt files together underneath one subdirectory, which allows me to set the encoding to UTF-8 on the directory, and then any file I add there will have UTF-8 by default.  However, I'm still interested in the general question of whether or not wildcard encoding preferences are possible.